# Mongo using 26GB of memory, is it bad?

Tags: mongodb

I was trying to benchmark my mongodb servers lately, and I am guessing they are kind of overloaded, this is the result of serverStatus():

```
SECONDARY> db.serverStatus().mem
{
    "bits" : 64,
    "resident" : 26197,
    "virtual" : 161106,
    "supported" : true,
    "mapped" : 79994,
    "mappedWithJournal" : 159988
}
```

So if i understood right, MongoDB is using 26GB of memory. If my server has 32GB, and it is only running mongoDb, getting a new server and sharding my data will be a good idea??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way MongoDB caching works will end up using whatever memory is available. Performance will drop significantly when the resident portion bumps up against the total memory, but will depend on your data access patterns.  It's usually okay if not everything is in memory all the time, but you want to have room for your working set.   See [Working Set Size](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Checking+Server+Memory+Usage#CheckingServerMemoryUsage-WorkingSetSize) and [serverStatus().mem](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/server-status/#server-status-memory) for general advice and details.

Answer (score 3):

Everything Joshua said with one caveat, you want to always make sure you have some swap enabled.  Otherwise you may run into the OOM Killer issues, see here:

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/The+Linux+Out+of+Memory+OOM+Killer

Basically, a busy MongoDB, with enough data will trend towards the maximum memory usage and then stay there.  This is not indicative of a problem per se, and is usually exactly what should happen.  You should [look](https://serverfault.com/questions/408100/mongodb-and-datasets-that-dont-fit-in-ram-no-matter-how-hard-you-shove/408182#408182) [elsewhere](https://serverfault.com/questions/413315/diagnosing-mongodb-major-faulting-and-erratic-behavior/413457#413457) to [diagnose](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/21026/mongodb-optimization-on-high-data/21048#21048) the source of any performance issues.